# Change text of button if it has a display of none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

I have a list of of checkboxes that are being used a search fields for a database. When someone clicks a checkbox it will show a button with the text from the label of that checkbox. However, I need that button to be have empty text when it is not visible (in the case of someone clicking the checkbox to hide the button).

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#locationAll').click(function() {
    var value = $('#locationAll').parent().text();
    $('#location-all-button').html(value + "&ensp;&times;").toggle('fast');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-popup').click(function() {
    $(this).hide('fast');
  });
  if ($('.search-popup').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).text("");
  };
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="all" id="locationAll" />All
</label>
<br>
<br>
<button class="search-popup btn" id="location-all-button"></button>
```

For some reason I can't make the button stay hidden before the checkbox on the example here but that isn't a problem in my full code. if you need more info let me know I might have missed something.

Comment: I don't understand why the text has to be blank. Are you trying to hide the button?

Comment: The backend guy is going to take that button text to execute a search. If the text is there but people clicked the checkbox to hide the button then it will mess with the search results.

Comment: So you only have 1 button for all of the checkboxes or more than 1 button?

Comment: Use `display: none !important;`

Comment: @SalielIrizarry also the backend guy will take what ever you (the front end guy I presume ) send him. I feel like there are better ways to do this, but I need to see more of your HTML structure.

Comment: There's multiple buttons for the multiple checkboxes  I have but they follow a very very similar structure. And i suppose there is but he told me this is fine.

Comment: why not use add button to add to the list and a drop-down to pick what to be added?

Comment: Because there are multiple input fields and they're all using this method. For the checkboxes, it just happens that for the particular thing they're searching, this is the easiest method for users. Also, I should mention that this is only a problem with the checkbox button even though they have the same markup as the other buttons.

Comment: @SalielIrizarry What about something like this? https://jsbin.com/qokubebofe/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for the try but when I inspect the element and hide the button it still has the text in the HTML. I've been thinking about what you said earlier though and I'm going to try using "value" now. I still need to find a way to remove the given value when the button is hidden however...

Comment: @SalielIrizarry did you click the "Get Values" button? I doesn't matter what text the button has if you can target the buttons that only need to be sent correct?

Comment: OMG. You are a life saver thank you so much! Sorry I'm such a klutz haha

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I changed a few things. I made this work for any checkbox that follows the naming scheme I made really quickly. The scheme is the id of the button = the "button-"+id. Also I hiding all buttons with a class right form the start to set their default state.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    \\change to allow all checkboxes to trigger
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function()
    {
       \\change the id so it match a button when add "button-" to the start
       \\this allows me to target the matching button with any chechbox 
       $('#button-'+$(this).attr('id')).toggle('fast');
    });
    $('.search-popup').click(function()
    {
       $(this).hide('fast');
       \\ sets the check box to false so it not checked when you close it
       $("#"+$(this).text().replace(" &ensp;&times;","")).attr('checked', false);
    });

   \\hides all buttons right form the start
   $('button.search-popup').each(function()
   {
       $(this).hide();
   });
});

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="all" id="All" />All
</label>
<br>
<br>
<button class="search-popup btn" id="button-All">All &ensp;&times;</button>
```

now if you want to create and remove buttons when a checkbox has changed state you can add an if state meant in that checks to see if the button with the matching id exists or not,!$(tag).size().